# Finding prefix exists in a list of words

Tags: java

Right now, I have a method that is supposed to use binary search to find if a prefix is in a list.

For example, user enters "ca" and if dictionary contains "cat", then the method should return true.

This is my method and along it is a helper method. The problem I have right now is that when I call the recursive method and the prefix is greater than the words in the dictionary, I will get an index out of bounds error because of the substring() method.

I'm using this method in conjunction with a recursive function in order to find all permutations of a string. (The generateWords() method).

**How can I modify this function in order to check whether a prefix is in a list of words given that the list of words have words of varying lengths?**

```
public boolean findPrefix(String Prefix){
        return findBinaryPrefix(listOfWords, Prefix,0, listOfWords.size()-1, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Helper function for findPrefix.
     * @param list arraylist
     * @param prefix prefix you want to find
     * @param low lowest index
     * @param high highest index of the array.
     * @return returns true if prefix is in the dictionary, else false.
     */
    private boolean findBinaryPrefix(ArrayList<String> list, String prefix, int low, int high, int prefixLength){
        int charCounter = prefixLength;

        if(low>high){
            return false;
        }
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        if(list.get(mid).substring(0, charCounter).equals(prefix.substring(0, charCounter))){
            //If the word is equal, then that's the base case.
            return true;
        }

        else if (list.get(mid).substring(0, charCounter).compareTo(prefix.substring(0, charCounter)) < 0){
            return findBinaryPrefix(list, prefix, mid+1, high, charCounter);
        }
        else
            return findBinaryPrefix(list, prefix, low, mid-1, charCounter);
    }


private ArrayList<String> generateWords(Dictionary dict,String prefix, String seq){


        if(seq.length() == 0){
            if(dict.findWord(prefix)){
                permList.add(prefix);
            }

        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0;i<seq.length(); i++){
                if(!dict.findPrefix(prefix)){break;}
                //if prefix is not even in dictionary, don't bother generating.

                //generate permutations when the character is in a different position with each iteration of the loop.
                generateWords(dict, prefix + seq.charAt(i) ,seq.substring(0,i) + seq.substring(i+1, seq.length()));
            }
        }

        return permList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
if(list.get(mid).length() < charCounter) {
 //do something
}
```

Comment: How would that be able to make the comparison in the end?